# Alfresco 4.0 and Liferay Integration?

Tags: liferay, integration, alfresco

I want to know what all integrations is possible for alfresco 4.0 & liferay as i was googling it and could find some links also but most are for alfresco 3+.

http://www.liferay.com/web/jonas.yuan/blog/-/blogs/integrating-alfresco-3-4-in-liferay-6-1-via-cmis-1-0

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Alfresco+Portlet

http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay- http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/document-library-portlet

Can anybody help for 4.0?

Regards.

Comment: Did you try any of those anyway? (There have been changes since Alfresco 3.4, but they may well not have affected the integration points)

Comment: I was trying to use webscript container part from http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Alfresco+integration but it says that page does not exist.

Comment: Nest i was trying on doclib portlet @ https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Doclib_Portlet but it is not supported for Liferay 6.0 onwards.Again stuck up.

Comment: I am trying to use Rivet AWPr portlet @ http://wiki.rivetlogic.com/display/AWPr/About+AWPr but can not see any support as such. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Liferay 6.1, you can try adding Alfresco as a new repository.

If you follow the tutorial on [Liferay wiki](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/CMIS+Repository) you should be able to access Alfresco documents directly from Documents and Media portlet. But I haven't tried it myself yet.